# Opening a SQLiteConnection on a binary stream instead of a file?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Is it possible to open a SQLiteConnection on a binary stream without first saving it to disk?  Surely there's a way to 'trick' the connection into thinking the stream is a file.  I mean, internally that's what it's doing anyway, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about `System.Data.SQLite` from http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), then you can set the file name on your connection string to `:memory:` and it should create an in-memory database.

```
var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data source=:memory:");
```

Comment: As I understand it, this creates an empty in-memory db and I don't see a way to initialize it with a byte stream.

Comment: Correct. The SQLite `":memory:"` is a special case inside the system and I'm not sure there is a good way to initialize that with some arbitrary byte stream, especially not from C#. In C++ and a POSIX OS, I would suggest a tempfs file, but I can't really speak to Windows.