# Loading an SQLite database from a byte stream in .NET

Tags: .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm trying to load an SQLite database that will be embedded in my executable as a resource.  For those who are curious, it is because I use a small SQLite database to store configuration data, and I'd like to ship the default configuration embedded inside the executable (I hate having to carry files along with a program).

This would just be the default configuration.  That is, I do not need to modify this configuration.  It is static and cannot be changed after my program has been built.

I am using the System.Data.SQLite wrapper for SQLite.

I can get access to a byte stream like this:

```cs
using (var stream =
          Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)) {
    // use of "stream" here.
}
```

However, I am at a loss with regards to creating an `SQLiteConnection` object from this stream.

The easy way out would be to simply spawn a new configuration file every time the program loads, and then tell SQLite to read from that file.  This would probably work, but I would like to avoid that technique - I plan on reusing my solution to this problem to also include internationalization support (where each language is a [compressed] SQLite database and the default language is embedded in the executable - a user could add other languages my simply copying other language databases to the working directory of the program).

I'm not concerned with the memory cost of holding this database in memory.  It will be very small (likely less than 50 KiB), so that does not bother me.  Obviously if this was a larger database, this might be an issue.

Finally, I'm aware that this may be seen as a poor way to store a configuration.  While I agree that a plaintext-based solution is nice for cases when the user enters all his/her settings manually, this would mostly be used for settings that the user does not explicitly define.  For example, to store the positions of various docking windows in an application, or to store data about where internal resources might be found.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 7 years later and wondering if you ever got a solution to this that allowed you to save a sql lite db to a binary from memory or load it from a stream?

Comment: Nope. To be honest, I have no idea what I was even trying to do here (I was just in my 2nd year of university at the time).

If I had to implement this now, I'd probably just store the necessary SQL text in the binary instead, as the selected answer suggests.

Comment: I have a business case for it so your university question wasn't that bad in the scheme of things.  Mainly Azure file IO is extremely slow we needed to produce a large sql lite db to send downstream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like this functionality is not inmplemented in a System.Data.SQLite provider. You can't even save in-memory database to a file (i.e. in a binary format), only in form of an SQL dump.

So one of the solutions is to store SQL code for database creation in a resource. Then create in memory db each time application starts.

Comment: I've considered that, and at this point it seems like the only way to go.  Either way, it shouldn't be terribly large: I was going to try to compress the resource anyways (since SQLite databases with lots of text seem to compress nicely).

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to use this for your connection string:

```
Data source=:memory:
```

See here for example: [Opening a SQLiteConnection on a binary stream instead of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868338/opening-a-sqliteconnection-on-a-binary-stream-instead-of-a-file)

Comment: Yes, and that would be good if I wanted to start with an empty database.  But in this case, I have an existing binary stream that I would like it to read as a database, as opposed to simply opening a new one.

Comment: @Ethan: I don't see anything in the example I posted about this being an empty database.  But to be honest, I've never really used SQLite before and was just trying to help, so I may not know what I'm talking about :)

Comment: Well, perhaps there is a way to do it, but the issue with your example is that there is no where for me to pass the binary stream.  If this were unmanaged code, I may be able to do something ridiculous, like manually pass the address/size of the stream in memory, but I'm fairly certain that is not possible in .NET.